# Работа с файлами. Чтение, запись в файл

Tags: java

Метод, который будет:

1. принимать на вход файл (объект `java.util.File`),
2. вызывать `openFile(); writeToFile(); closeFile();` - реализацию этих методов писать не нужно, просто вызвать их по очереди в теле нашего метода
3. нужно организовать в методе *try-catch* блок, с отловом всех исключений и выводом на экран ошибок, если вдруг случатся.

Как вообще задачи похожего типа решать?

Comment: посмотри примеры работы с файлами, там есть все то, что тебе нужно

Comment: То есть, метод, по сути, должен состоять из пяти строк - три на вызов тех методов и две на обработку ошибок. Весь код уже написан практически в самой задаче. Что сложного то, не пойму? Это ж даже не сортировка пузырьком.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
private static String text = "This new text \nThis new text2\n";
private static String fileName = "C://blog/a.txt";

public static void write(String fileName, String text) {
//Определяем файл
File file = new File(fileName);

try {
    //проверяем, что если файл не существует то создаем его
    if(!file.exists()){
        file.createNewFile();
    }

    //PrintWriter обеспечит возможности записи в файл
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());

    try {
        //Записываем текст у файл
        out.print(text);
    } finally {
        //После чего мы должны закрыть файл
        //Иначе файл не запишется
        out.close();
    }
} catch(IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
}
```

**P.S.: первая ссылка в гугле, так, если что**

Comment: Спасибо большое,буду разбираться, я новичек, только начинаю